# Css hover text information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I need some help!
I'm doing website, and i'm having a problem with a thing. I have  a `<h1>` and a image next to it, that image is a question mark. And i want that when i mouse hover that question mark it appears the div that i made with the information... i saw lots of topics answered in that forum but none of them is working, pls help me!

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>branch<img id="help" src="Questionmark.png"></img></h1>
<div id="information">Branch is...</div>
<script>
var e = document.getElementById('help');
e.onmouseover = function() {
document.getElementById('information').style.display = 'block';
}
e.onmouseout = function() {
document.getElementById('information').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pls tell me what to do, maybe there is a easy way... i tried css but also didn't work...

Comment: You code is working. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: Yep, it works. You may want to remove the incorrect `</img>`, though.

Comment: The only suggestion I would make is to set `#information` to `display:none` with CSS, so the element is hidden by default.  Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NUBWs/

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after#Tooltips

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to go with css.

> If you are doing layout, use CSS, if you are setting the look and feel
>   use CSS, if your doing animation use CSS3
>
> If you attach event handlers or reacting to user input use JavaScript.
>
> Note that people use JavaScript instead of CSS for browser support.
>   There are other solutions like emulating CSS features using
>   javascript.

[source](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/when-a-task-can-be-accomplished-by-either-javascript-or-css-is-it-better-to-use)

**css**

```
#information{
    display:none;
}

h1:hover + #information{
    display:block;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QzNV/4/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple tooltip kind of thing, then you can use this code

```
<h1>
     branch<img id="help" src="Questionmark.png"></img>
     <div id="information">Branch is...</div>
</h1>

h1{
    position: relative;
}
h1 img{
    cursor: pointer;
}
#information{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background: red;
}
h1 img:hover + #information{
    display: block;
}
```

Check this link http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/G83WB/2/