# Show text when hover over an element

Tags: css

You know often if you hold your cursor over some element, say button, after a second or so it shows a text (usually in yellow background) with a tip what this button does.

How can I do this in css? I want that this default behavior: you hover your cursor and after some delay it shows the text.

Comment: You may want to research this question. I'd guess that if you just put the title into Google you would get your answer.

Comment: This is similar to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588299/css-hover-text-information The resulting jsfiddle is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24588299/css-hover-text-information

Answer (score 1):

You have a good documentation [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is exactly what you are looking for: 
It's that simple yellow box that you want.

http://www.menucool.com/tooltip/css-tooltip